# Convert MySQL syntax into ODBC on JSON encoding

Tags: php, mysql, json, odbc

I am working on a Full Calendar that i found an example online. However, the example is using MySQL as his database, but my database is Microsoft Access with ODBC as bridge.

My question is how can i change this line of code into MSSQL usable code.

The full code to fetch data from database is here:

```
$json = array();


 $requete = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id";


 try {
    require "db_config.php";
 } catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }


 $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));


 echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

But i cant find any solution to change the json_encode part into MSSQL usable

Which is below:

```
$resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));


 echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Comment: *but my database is ODBC.* ODBC is not a database, this is programming interface for accessing the database.

Comment: Sorry, ive editted my post. I am using Microsoft Access with odbc as api @Akina